# Mechanism behind GROUP BY in SQL considering the Order of Execution

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering the "SQL order of execution", how is it possible for the GROUP BY statement to work on a column that is to be made by the CASE WHEN operation in the SELECT statement?

example query:

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN COM_SALES_PRC > 1000000 THEN "good job"
    END AS Performance,
    COUNT(CUST_SEQ_NO) AS NumberofEmployees
    
FROM PREP_MONTHLY_STAT
GROUP BY Performance
```

While the above query is ran without an error, the one below gives me an error. Makes sense since WHERE statement would not know the alias to be given in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT  
    CASE
        WHEN COM_SALES_PRC > 1000000 THEN "good job"
    END AS Performance,
    COUNT(CUST_SEQ_NO) AS NumberofEmployees
    
FROM PREP_MONTHLY_STAT
WHERE Performance IS NOT NULL
```

**SQL order of execution**:
https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVE
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY
7. LIMIT

I'm pretty new to writing queries, and it would be very grateful if the answers are as detailed as possible. Thank you.

Comment: And the answer is, you can't, but this is a very commonly asked question, which you will be able to easily find the answer to.

Comment: does this hlep? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77130/how-do-i-select-data-with-a-case-statement-and-group-by

Comment: Note that MySQL (logically) doesn't follow that order to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that the existence of `COUNT(...)` implies a `GROUP BY`.  If you don't have one explicitly, then then entire tables is one "group".  `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc are "aggregates".

`WHERE` cannot refer to expressions in the `SELECT`.  `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` can refer to *aggregates* only after `GROUP BY` has aggregated them.

`WHERE Performance IS NOT NULL` could be changed to `HAVING Performance IS NOT NULL`

(I don't like having `SELECT` as 5.)

Some issues with your use of `COUNT`, plus more examples:

- `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL`.  Is that necessary in your case?  If not, then simply say `COUNT(*)`.
- You are probably getting the total number of employees.  If you just wanted the "good job" employees, then

  ```
    SELECT  
        COUNT(*) AS GoodJobEmployees
    FROM PREP_MONTHLY_STAT
    WHERE COM_SALES_PRC > 1000000
  ```
- If you wanted both the total and the "good job" counts:

  ```
    SELECT  
        SUM(COM_SALES_PRC > 1000000) AS GoodJobEmployees,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalEmployees
    FROM PREP_MONTHLY_STAT
  ```

If your *real* goal is more complex,let's see it.